# symmetric group of regular polyhedrons

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, group-actions, polyhedra

Let $\Delta^n$ be the regular $n$-simplex spanned by $(n+1)$ vertices, equipped with an Riemannian metric such that all the edges are of equal length. For example,

$\Delta^2$:

[image]

$\Delta^3$:

[image]

Let $c:=c(\Delta^n)$ be the center of $\Delta^n$. 
Consider the mapping space
$$
M=\{f: \Delta^n\to \mathbb{R}^n\mid f\text{ is injective and isometric, and }f (c)=0\}.
$$
I observe that
$$
\text{simplicial isomorphism group of }\Delta^n\cong \text{symmetric group }S_{n+1} \text{ permuting on the vertices of }\Delta^n.
$$
I define an equivalent relation $\sim$ on $M$ by setting
$$
f\sim g
$$
if and only if there exists a simplicial isomorphism $i$ of $\Delta^n$ such that 
$$
f=g\circ i.
$$
I find that $M/\sim$ is called the [polyhedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedral_group) of $\Delta^n$.

**Question:** ***Are there any references about the topological structure of this mapping space $M/\sim$?***

***I want to know the cohomology ring 
$
H^*(M/\sim;\mathbb{Z}_2)
$?***

Answer (score 4):

It will make no difference if you define $\Delta^n$ in such a way that $c=0$.  In that case it is not hard to see that any isometric embedding is linear, so $M=O(n)$.  It follows that $M/\sim=O(n)/\Sigma_{n+1}=SO(n)/A_{n+1}$.  We therefore have a Serre spectral sequence 
$$ H^i(A_{n+1};H^j(SO(n);\mathbb{Z}/2)) \Longrightarrow H^{i+j}(M/\sim;\mathbb{Z}/2). $$
In principle, the $E^2$ term involves the group cohomology of $H^*(SO(n))$ as a module over $A_{n+1}$.  However, given any $g\in A_{n+1}$ we can choose a path in $SO(n)$ connecting $g$ to $1$, and it follows that the action of $g$ on $SO(n)$ is homotopic to the identity, and so acts as the identity on cohomology.  Thus, the $E^2$ term can be rewritten as
$$ H^i(A_{n+1};\mathbb{Z}/2) \otimes H^j(SO(n);\mathbb{Z}/2). $$
The mod $2$ cohomology groups of $SO(n)$ and $\Sigma_{n+1}$ are well known, although those of $\Sigma_{n+1}$ are complicated.  It should not be hard to deduce the cohomology groups of $A_{n+1}$.  However, I would guess that there are many differentials in the spectral sequence unless $n$ is very small.

Comment: The mod $p$ cohomology of $A_n$ was computed by Ben Mann in 1985: http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.mmj/1029003238 
Though I would not describe the results as easy to parse.